# How to use a string array returned from a function?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a function that returns a `string array`

```
Function getAr() As String
Dim tmpAr(3) As String
getAr(0) = "Hallo"
getAr(1) = "I"
getAr(2) = "Am"
getAr(3) = "I"
getAr = tmpAr
End Function
```

In a `Sub` I want to reassign the returned string array like

```
Sub test()
Dim tmpAr() As String
ReDim tmpAr(UBound(getAr))
Debug.Print tmpAr(0)
Debug.Print tmpAr(1)
End Sub
```

The error is

> assigning to data field is not possible.

I guess that is because I have to dimension the `strAr` to the same dimension as the `myfunc` arry. But I just do not get that information.

Could anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know the dimension to assign an array, but your code wasn't correct.

Here is my amended version :

```
Function getAr() As String()

Dim tmpAr(3) As String

tmpAr(0) = "Hallo"
tmpAr(1) = "I"
tmpAr(2) = "Am"
tmpAr(3) = "I"

getAr = tmpAr
End Function
```

Notice the `String()`, this is how you declare the type of a function returning an array.

Also, you were dimensionning `tmpAr` and tried to affect values to `getAr` which wasn't set and as you started, it is much easier to work with a temp variable that you'll assign to the function's output at the end of the manipulations.

And your ReDim `ReDim tmpAr(UBound(getAr))` was working but did not pass the array, this how you do it `tmpAr = getAr` and you don't even need to use `ReDim` before! ;)

```
Sub test()
Dim tmpAr() As String
tmpAr = getAr

Debug.Print tmpAr(0)
Debug.Print tmpAr(1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function and sub both need changing:

```
Function getAr() As String()
    Dim tmpAr(3)              As String
    tmpAr(0) = "Hallo"
    tmpAr(1) = "I"
    tmpAr(2) = "Am"
    tmpAr(3) = "I"
    getAr = tmpAr
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim tmpAr()               As String
    tmpAr = getAr
    Debug.Print tmpAr(0)
    Debug.Print tmpAr(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Did not know that tmpAr = getAr makes dimensioning of tmpAr redundant. Good to know! Thanks a lot!